# BLKRASET: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, mongodb

I'm receiving this error

> BLKRASET: Inappropriate ioctl for device

when trying to run

> sudo blockdev --setra 256 /data

on my Linux server. The server is being used as a MongoDB server and /data is where it stores it's data.

I initially tried to run this command when I received this warning when starting my MongoDB shell:

> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten]
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Readahead for
>   /data/db is set to 2048KB
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] ** We suggest setting it to
>   256KB (512 sectors) or less
>
> Wed Mar 20 22:40:49.850 [initandlisten] **
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead

The blockdev --setra command is supposed to set the readahead value for that directory and resolve the issue but I'm running into this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blockdev` command operates on block devices (disks), not directories. You need to pass it the name of the device in `/dev/` where your data directory is stored. If you `df /data` it will tell you which device is currently mounted there. Then you can run `blockdev --setra 512 /dev/whatever`